# scrapy startproject tutorial: Error when I execute this command

Tags: python, scrapy, pip

```
C:\Windows\system32>scrapy startproject tutorial
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('Scrapy==0.24.4', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 353, in load_entry
_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2302, in load_entr
y_point
return ep.load()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in load
entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
import _monkeypatches
ImportError: No module named '_monkeypatches'
```

I'm a newbie in scrapy & python. I was trying to create a scrapy project but wasn't able to. I have installed pip, setuptools, lxml and scrapy.

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip list
cffi (0.8.6)
cryptography (0.5.4)
cssselect (0.9.1)
lxml (3.4.0)
pip (1.5.6)
pycparser (2.10)
pyOpenSSL (0.14)
queuelib (1.2.2)
Scrapy (0.24.4)
setuptools (2.1)
six (1.8.0)
Twisted (14.0.2)
w3lib (1.10.0)
zope.interface (4.1.1)
```

Please help! I've been searching around but still couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy is supported under Python 2.7 only at the moment. You'll need to install 2.7 for this to work.

Comment: That solved the problem but another problem pops up when I run scrapy startproject tutorial. Here's the ques, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979938/scrapy-startproject-tutorial-error-when-running-this-command