# scrapy startproject tutorial: Error when running this command

Tags: python, scrapy

I got this error when I was trying to create a new Scrapy project.

```
C:\Windows\system32>Scrapy startproject tutorial
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_sslverify.py:184: UserWarning: Y
ou do not have the service_identity module installed. Please install it from <ht
tps://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity>. Without the service_identity modul
e and a recent enough pyOpenSSL tosupport it, Twisted can perform only rudimenta
ry TLS client hostnameverification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings ma
y be rejected.
verifyHostname, VerificationError = _selectVerifyImplementation()
New Scrapy project 'tutorial' created in:
C:\Windows\system32\tutorial

You can start your first spider with:
cd tutorial
scrapy genspider example example.com
```

Comment: off topic, why you created your project in system32 directory?

Comment: I don't see any error, there's only a warning in the content you post.

Comment: @salmanwahed ,it was created there since the beginning. Is that something that is not supposed to be there?

Comment: yes. system32 is a directory for the system files of windows operating system. you may create your project somewhere like `C:\Users\<user>` directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a warning that twisted won't be able to identify SSL sites. To get rid of the warning install the service_identity module:

```
pip install service_identity
```